# $anchorScroll not functioning properly

Tags: angularjs, anchor-scroll

On the click of a button i want the page to scroll a particular div `bottom`.

The 1st time i click, the page is going to the very top and the initial url  `http://localhost:8000` becomes `http://localhost:8000/#/bottom`(*why is it not going to the `div` i mentioned*).

The 2nd time i click the button, the url becomes 
`http://localhost:8000/#/bottom#bottom` and it goes to the div `bottom`(*which is what i want*).

How do i deal with this ?

**code snippet**

```
$location.hash('bottom');
$anchorScroll();
```

Thanks in advance

Do ask for more explanation if required . . .

Comment: maybe you use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and page re-render on hash change?

Comment: no i am not using ui-router

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need help, but have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890060/using-location-and-anchorscroll-to-scroll-a-table-row-into-view) question?

Anyway, I also use one button to do a anchor scroll:

```
<button ng-click="app.gotoAnchor('destination')">GO!</button>
(...)
<div id="destination" style="height:1px;"></div>
```

And I just used a combination of AngularJS documentation [examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) and the SO question I mentioned before, to make this function:

```
function gotoAnchor(anchor){
      if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
        // set the $location.hash to `newHash` and
        // $anchorScroll will automatically scroll to it
        $timeout(function() {
          $location.hash(anchor);
        });
      } else {
        // call $anchorScroll() explicitly,
        // since $location.hash hasn't changed
        $anchorScroll();
      }
    }
```

Being the `$timeout` call the one that made this work better.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

> ```
> <a href="#bottom">BOTTOM</a>
> <div style="height:700px"> this is boby </div>
> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/vietlink365" id="bottom">JOIN NOW!</a>
> ```

Comment: do keep some kind of explanation atleast