# $anchorScroll is not working in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, anchor-scroll

I am working on an app that submits the form and get the result from the server which followed by HTML table view. My input form is a bit big which covers whole the screen. When the table comes then I want automatically scroll down at the table view. I used $anchorScroll from angularJs. But I am not able to achieve the result what I want. I also used $timeout to make sure the table is already exist or not and then perform $anchorScroll, but still no success.  (based on this solution : [Using $location and $anchorScroll to scroll a table row into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890060/using-location-and-anchorscroll-to-scroll-a-table-row-into-view)

Hear is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-controller="searchController as searchCtrl" id="scrollArea">
    <form>
       //HTML input elements

       <div class="buttons">
           <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="searchCtrl.gotoTable('resultTable')">Start</md-button>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- Smart Table for displaying result -->
<div class="rtable" ng-show = "searchCtrl.tableViewData.length > 0" id="resultTable">

//table content

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp')

.controller("searchController", function($log, searchService, $scope, $location, $anchorScroll, $timeout){
    var self = this;

 self.gotoTable = function(resultTable) 
    {
        $timeout(function() {
            $location.hash(resultTable);
            $anchorScroll();
        });
    };

});
```

I dont know why its not working?

Do i need to define the id scrollArea and resultTable in my CSS?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Based on Okazari's solution, I tried to put a another div with many br tag above at the very bottom of my HTML. Now When I refresh the page then it automatically scroll to that div tag without clicking Start. this is a bit weird. I also tried to cover the

```
 <div class="rtable" ng-show = "searchCtrl.tableViewData.length > 0" id="resultTable">
```

tag with another div tag with id = "resultTable".
But still it did not work.

Comment: what is `resultTable` in your controller? 
 Have you tested `$anchorScroll()` on just a `#` to see if that works?

Comment: @JoeLloyd : resultTable is the id of table. You can see in HTML second last <div>. This table I want to show.

Comment: could you try to reproduce you issue forking my plunker ?

Comment: sorry, it was a confusing update description because of format. I have updated now.

Comment: @Okazari : No, I just copied your code from plunker and tried. I think the whole issue is because of get and post request to the server.

Comment: @HarshSoni you should try to reproduce your issue into the plunker from now.

Answer (score 4):

You actually are invoking your function without any parameters

```
ng-click="searchCtrl.gotoTable()"
```

whereas in your controller you expect to have one :

```
self.gotoTable = function(resultTable)
```

Try something like this

```
ng-click="searchCtrl.gotoTable('resultTable')"
```

or this :

```
self.gotoTable = function() 
{
    $timeout(function() {
        $location.hash("resultTable");
        $anchorScroll();
    });
};
```

(just one, not both)

Hope it helped.

EDIT : Pretty sure that you can't go to a hidden div. As i said in comment your ng-show may be evaluated to true when you try to anchorscroll().

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bsmny3NBs2yjxaqoUCGr?p=preview) without ng-show. I'll build a tiny solution to avoid the ng-show issue.

To avoid this side effect, i wrapped the div with ng-show with another div.

```
<div id="resultTable">
 <div class="rtable" ng-show = "searchCtrl.tableViewData.length > 0">
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, i tried the both option one by one. But it still not working...:(

Comment: @HarshSoni I think i have an idea of the issue. You actually can't anchor scroll to an hidden div. Till you have a ng-show on the div you want to scroll to. The ng-show may be evaluated to true when the anchor-scroll trigger

Comment: Hey, I tried the same with covering the div tag with id, but still its not working. And i have updated the question. Please go through it. thanks.

Comment: **Not really helpful.**
I have injected $anchorScroll in controller.
**HTML : **
<button type="button" ng-click="testFunc();">Test</button>

**Controller :**
$scope.testFunc = function(){
 $anchorScroll();
}

I'm using this md-calendar directive.